# How can I mimic this select() function from R in python?

Tags: python, r

In R, if I want to manipulate columns of a data frame, I can just do something like this:

```
df %>% select(starts_with("main"),contains("ID"),everything(),-name)
```

The above statement brings anything that starts with "main" up front, followed by anything that contains "ID", then every other column in the data frame, and finally finishing it out by removing name column.

I need to be able to replicate the logic in Python but I can't seem to find a similar simple way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: That's one reason why I love R much more than Python... I still don't get why Python is so poplar in data analysis. lol

Comment: How does your complicated way looks like?

Comment: @ytu Yes, I love R as well, but I need to implement something into a script that requires some Python libraries that are not available in R.

Comment: that is what the [`reticulate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/introduction.html) package is for, use python in R.